# Should rope objectdb file be excluded from vcs?

Tags: python, version-control, visual-studio-code

The file `.vscode/.ropeproject/objectdb` has been modified (created) after applying refactoring to some python code (using DonJayamanne's `pythonVSCode` extension).

Should this `objectdb` file be excluded from versioning in `vscode`?

What info does it actually contains?

Answer (score 1):

So, I know this question is a year old, but I just had the same one and did some digging. It looks to me like the objectdb stores information about `rope.base.resources.File` objects, which include the local path of the file. As such, checking in the ObjectDB doesn't make a lot of sense. The `config.py` file, on the other hand, seems like it could be useful to share for a project.